# how to get around problems with group by, aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following query:

```
SELECT d.currentDate, t.ConfigId, t.value as value
FROM    #Dates AS d
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  t.value as value, t.FK_ShipDataSubsystemConfigId
            FROM    myTable AS t
            WHERE   t.[Timestamp] <= d.currentDate and t.ConfigId in (' + @IDList + ')
            and t.FK_DataSystemId <> 1
        ) AS t 
GROUP BY d.currentDate, t.ConfigId
)
```

where `Dates` is just a table holding a bunch of datetimes I am using to ensure I get the data at the intervals I need.

My problem is with the `group by` clause. The query doesn't work as is because `value` is not in the `group by` or an aggregate function. I tried grouping by `value` also to make the error go away, but it just gives me every single date in the interval I am selecting on matched to every single value -- not what I want. I should end up with a table with one row for each date/ConfigId pairing.

When I remove value from the `select` and just get the date and the `ConfigId`, it works fine. I get the exact number of rows I should be getting.

The table I'm pulling from looks like this:

```
PK_DataId    Timestamp        value     ConfigId
1            1/1/2015 12:00   234       5
2            1/1/2015 12:01   456       4
```

I am expecting to get back this:

```
Timestamp            value        ConfigId
1/1/2015 12:00:00    234          5
1/1/2015 12:00:00    456          4
```

Where I have a value for each configId/date pair from every fifteen minutes. When I add max(value) I only get one value for every time instead of different ones. When I group by value I get millions of rows, it looks like I am getting one row for each timestamp matched with each value from any other timestamp. I don't really understand what is happening.

How can I get those results while also selecting `value`?

Comment: Try including an `aggregate` function on the `value` column.

Comment: Which value do you want? Or are you looking for some kind of comma separated list?

Comment: You say you don't want every value of `value`, but you don't say which value of `value` you *do* want.  So which is it?  The highest?  Lowest?  Average?

Comment: Amen to the comment by @BaconBits.  And some sample data would be nice.

Comment: google and learn about GROUP BY and  Aggregate Functions in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want `top 1` in the `apply`:

```
SELECT d.currentDate, t.ConfigId, t.value as value
FROM #Dates d OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT  TOP 1 t.value as value, t.FK_ShipDataSubsystemConfigId
      FROM    myTable AS t
      WHERE   t.[Timestamp] <= d.currentDate and
              t.ConfigId in (' + @IDList + ') and
              t.FK_DataSystemId <> 1
     ORDER BY t.[Timestamp] DESC
    ) t ;
```

EDIT:

If you need one row for each `config` and time:

```
SELECT d.currentDate, t.ConfigId, t.value as value
FROM #Dates d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT FK_ShipDataSubsystemConfigId
      FROM myTable
      WHERE t.ConfigId in (' + @IDList + ')
     ) c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT  TOP 1 t.value as value, t.FK_ShipDataSubsystemConfigId
      FROM    myTable AS t
      WHERE   t.[Timestamp] <= d.currentDate and
              t.ConfigId = c.FK_ShipDataSubsystemConfigId and
              t.FK_DataSystemId <> 1
      ORDER BY t.[Timestamp] DESC
     ) t ;
```

Same basic idea, but this needs to generate all the rows for all configs and the dates before the `outer apply`.

Comment: It's closer, I am getting different values now. But I am only getting one row for each time, when I should have one row for each time/configId.

Answer (score 0):

Without real data is really hard to understand your question.

Im going to guess you dont want Aggregeted function like.

```
SELECT d.currentDate, t.ConfigId, 
  MAX(t.value) as maxvalue, 
  MIN(t.value) as minvalue,
  COUNT(t.value) as totalvalue
```

So im going with you are looking for

[simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

```
ANDY   |  A100
ANDY   |  B391
ANDY   |  X010
TOM    |  A100
TOM    |  A510
```

returns:

```
ANDY   |  A100 / B391 / X010
TOM    |  A100 / A510
```

Comment: I added some sample data if that helps

Comment: Looks like you dont need group by. Because only item for each date. Either remove the `GROUP BY` or put a bigger sample.